# Not able to Increase Quota Limits for Google My Business Management API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota, google-my-business-api

We are trying to use My Business Management API , and we are not having appropriate quota limit for same. We requested to increase the quota limit couple of weeks back , but still we don’t have any increased quota or updates.
Can you help us how to get the quota revised with higher limits.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a quota request, an email is sent acknowledging the request and another one a few hours/days later with an approve/deny. Check your Spam folder. You can try again with a new request.